# ms access query error

Tags: ms-access

I'm converting my database from SQL Server to MS Access.

This query works fine in SQL Server, but it has syntax error in MS-Access.

So what is wrong with this SQL statement??

```
select * 
from Students 
left join (select Lessons.StudentID, COUNT(*) as LessonsCount 
           from Lessons 
           group by Lessons.StudentID) as c on c.StudentID = Students.ID  
left join (select Tests.StudentID, count(*) as TestsCount 
           from Tests 
           group by Tests.StudentID) as dd on dd.StudentID = c.StudentID
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access SQL requires parentheses with multiple joins.  The fail-safe way to deal with that issue is to set up your joins in the query designer, and let Access add the parentheses it wants.

It may come out looking something like this:

```
select * 
from (Students 
left join [select Lessons.StudentID, COUNT(*) as LessonsCount 
           from Lessons 
           group by Lessons.StudentID]. as c on c.StudentID = Students.ID) 
left join [select Tests.StudentID, count(*) as TestsCount 
           from Tests 
           group by Tests.StudentID]. as dd on dd.StudentID = c.StudentID
```

A side effect with the query designer is that it tends to convert subqueries from this form

```
(SELECT some_field FROM some_table) AS sub
```

to this ...

```
[SELECT some_field FROM some_table]. AS sub
```

Comment: there is an extra ) near  "group by Lessons.StudentID"
i removed it and it works fine . thanks a lot .

Comment: I see what you mean.  Sorry I didn't notice it.  Fixed.